# Trouble building a sample and running a module in Titanium Mobile

Tags: android, mobile, module, titanium, appcelerator

I'm attempting to create an Android module. I've read and followed the steps in the guide of creating an android module provided by the appcelerator wiki.

However I encountered a few problems along the way. I created the module using Titanium Studio, imported into eclipse and I was shown with a errors in the java file. http://min.us/mbj8ktGHgh#1o

I proceeded on ignoring the errors and attempt to build the module as instructed by the guide. Right click on ant.xml and run the first option. The build failed because it failed to find the Android NDK. I solved that by downloading the Android NDK and adding "android.ndk=path" to the build.properties. Ran it again and encountered another problem. This time it failed to find the libs folder. http://min.us/mbj8ktGHgh#2o

What went wrong?

Comment: Titanium has been given me problems with spaces in the paths. Try to move it. Also note the warning given above the error you should move your project